# How can I increment the Xpath in webdriver script?

Tags: selenium

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='MyGrid']/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/b")).getText();

.//*@id='MyGrid']/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/b
.//*[@id='MyGrid']/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/b
```

Need to increment above xpaths and performs actions.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use a for loop

get total xpaths list size

    List<WebElement> xpaths = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='MyGrid']/tbody/tr"));

    //iterate through the list

        for(int i=0;i<xpaths.size();i++){

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='MyGrid']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/b"));//perform actions
        }

    }
```